# How do I control the order of form fields in Django?

Tags: django, forms, django-templates

Given that I have a generic form like this:

```
from django import forms
class TimesForm(forms.Form):
     hours = forms.DecimalField()
     description = forms.CharField()
     topic = forms.CharField()
```

And I want to render this form in html,
what is the best way to dynamically control the order of appearance?
In other words, the user should be able to control the order in which those input fields are displayed on the screen.

While I was able to iterate through the fields like this:

```
{% for field in form %}
{{field}}
{% endfor %}
```

I did not find a proper way to control the order of appearance of the input fields. How do I best do that?

Comment: You access to the form's fields this way `{{form.hours}}`,  `{{form.description}}` etc.

Comment: If the user has to control it, just render some of them as hidden and use JS to display/hide some fields.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [the "Notes on field ordering" section of Django's forms API documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#notes-on-field-ordering):

> There are several other ways to customize the order:
>
> `Form.field_order`
>
> By default `Form.field_order=None`, which retains the order in which you define the fields in your form class. If `field_order` is a list of field names, the fields are ordered as specified by the list and remaining fields are appended according to the default order. Unknown field names in the list are ignored. This makes it possible to disable a field in a subclass by setting it to `None` without having to redefine ordering.
>
> You can also use the `Form.field_order` argument to a `Form` to override the field order. If a `Form` defines `field_order` *and* you include `field_order` when instantiating the `Form`, then the latter `field_order` will have precedence.
>
> `Form.order_fields(field_order)`
>
> You may rearrange the fields any time using `order_fields()` with a list of field names as in `field_order`.